# PHP Radio Button Value Inside Post Array

Tags: php, forms, post, radio-button

I am pretty new to PHP and I have these two Radio Buttons.

```
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" checked = "checked" /> Female
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" />
```

I'm trying to see which one was selected by doing something like this...

```
$radio = $_POST["gender"];
```

How would I know which one was selected?

Comment: Only the selected one is sent to the server.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know how it was going to send.

Comment: $radio has value of selected radio button.

Comment: thanks for this question, it was exactly what I was looking for - i know these type of comments generally are frowned upon, but keep up the good work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only the selected checkbox will be sent to your server.  To check in your code which one was selected, you can use:

```
if($_POST['gender'] === 'female') {
    //Female selected
}
else if($_POST['gender'] === 'male') {
    //Male selected
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for, I don't know why I was down voted though...

Answer (score 1):

The variable `$radio` will have the value of the `<input>` checked.